# C - Access a certain row or column in a matrix

Tags: c

I want to know how I can print a certain row, certain column and the anti diagonal in an NxN matrix. So far I know how to print the matrix itself and the main diagonal. As you can see in the code I'm printing the main diagonal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int r1, c1;
    printf("\n Enter number of rows for M1");
    scanf("%d", &r1);
    printf("\n Enter number of columns for M1");
    scanf("%d", &c1);
    int m1[r1][c1];
    // int m2[][];
    int i, j;
    printf("\n Enter first Matrix: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < r1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c1; j++){
            scanf("%d", &m1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < r1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c1; j++){
            if(i == j){
                printf("%d", m1[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can yoi share the expected output?

Comment: Reverse the loop? `for(i = r1-1; i >=0; i--){for(j = c1-1; j >=0; j--){`....

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Let's say i enter a matrix 3x3 and i only want to print out the first row. Or the two elements from the first row. Or the first column etc.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp This way i will get the anti diagonal?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `for(i = r1-1; i >=0; i--){for(j = 0; j < c1; j++){` Lower left to upper right.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you now i need to know the two other things. Do you happen to know?

Comment: You need to figure out the logic instead of just copy pasting the code? Did you try to understand what's the logic behind Johnny's code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya By reversing the loop it counts from the last element on the last row instead of the first element on the first row. But that's not what i asked, that only takes the same(main) diagonal and reverses it. Instead of lets say the main diagonal is 1 5 9 i get 9 5 1. What i also want to know is how to get the other diagonal. Lets say
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 
I want to get 3 5 7. Also i want to know how can i get only 2 and 3 or only the first row or column. Or just a specific number.

Comment: Try reversing both the loops.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I still get the same 9 5 1 instead of 1 5 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exercise is supposed to teach you how to translate a task into the correct loop.

In order to understand how to do that, I'd suggest this way:
Take a specific example (matrix), and write down the expected result. Then try to reverse-engineer it to the right loop code by understanding **the indices pattern**:

Let's take this matrix:

```
1 6 4 3
9 3 5 2
3 3 8 0
1 5 4 4
```

**Example 1 - Main diagonal**

Expected result would be `1384`
which is practically cells (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3). Now, look at this list of indices **and figure out the pattern** - it's one index that increments in every iteration ==> one index (one loop) is enough:

```
for(i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
    printf("%d", m1[i][i]);
}
```

**Example 2 - Anti diagonal**

Expected result would be `3531` which is practically cells (0,3) (1,2) (2,1) (3,0). Again, look at this list of indices **and figure out the pattern** - it's one index that increments in every iteration and the other one decrements. But if you think about it, **the second index is a function of the first one**. That means that also this one can be done with one index only:

```
for(i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
    printf("%d", m1[i][r1 - i + 1]);
}
```

Because `second-index = r1 - first-index + 1`, always.

I tried to explain here how you should go about thinking and writing the correct loop given a task. Now try to use this method for the rest of your tasks - a certain row and a certain column (it's even easier than the diagonals).

For row 2 the indices will be (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) - so what's the pattern?

Good luck.

Comment: This answers everything. Thank you i appreciate the help and the good explanation.